# Number not getting added in mysql database format ( number - number )

Tags: php, mysqli, numbers

I need to add data in my database and one way or the other the format must be like,

0 - 0 or 1 - 5

i have tryed =>
 mysqli_real_escape_string();

but did not work.

i have also tryed changing the sign to / , * , +, exp.

```
PHP 
$dataBase->_insertDataBase('tableNaam', $input);

function _insertDataBase($tabel,$input){ 

    $velden='';
    $waarden='';
    $i=0;

    foreach($input AS $key=>$value){
        $i=$i+1;
        if($i !== count($input)){
            $a=', ';
        }else{
            $a='';
        }            
        $velden.=$key.$a;
        $waarden.=$value.$a;
        unset($a);
    }  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tabel`($velden) VALUES ($waarden)";
    $this->_conn()->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the PHP?

Comment: `but did not work` is NOT how you describe when something doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your table? As in data types etc and the SQL you have tried?

Comment: what type is the field? int, varchar... ?

Comment: And also, show us a `var_dump()` of `$input`... how does that look like?

Comment: You are dynamically building the insert query. Please do `var_dump($sql)` (after the `$sql` var, but before the `query()` call), then test the query in adminer or phpMyAdmin, to see if it works. Please note, that you can do the `count($input)` before the foreach, else you are count'ing the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your SQL statement is giving the equation 5-1 as a value, so the server is doing the math and inserting 4 just like you told it to.  You need tell it that it's a literal string by surrounding the values with apostrophe's  (i.e.  '5-1').

Replace:

```
foreach ($input AS $key => $value) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    if ($i !== count($input)) {
        $a = ', ';
    } else {
        $a = '';
    }
    $velden .= $key . $a;
    $waarden .= $value . $a;
    unset($a);
}
```

With:

```
$velden = array();
$waarden = array();
foreach ($input AS $key => $value) {
    $velden[] = $key;
    $waarden[] = $value;
}
$velden = implode(',', $velden);
$waarden = "'" . implode("','", $waarden) . "'";
```

Or possibly even:

```
$velden = array_keys($input);
$waarden = array_values($input);
$velden = implode(',', $velden);
$waarden = "'" . implode("','", $waarden) . "'";
```